# Dell Ubuntu Super Key maximize a window vertically not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, dell

I am just setting up my new Dell XPS Developer Edition with Ubuntu pre-installed but I can't get the super-key to work properly. I removed dell-super-key package and configured the key to open the dash in ccsm. All good, however the next thing that is missing is the "ctrl+super+arrow key" short-cut command to resize windows to the left and right part of the screen. Documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-nav.html). Anyone know how to configure this to work as it should?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. In ccsm under window management / grid it is possible to configure the short cut.